# how to get every images's pixel values of "ImageCollection" in GEE

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, pixel

I create a Sentinel-2 cloud free mosaic image with Google Earth Engine and exported the image to an Earth Engine asset.

I know the image that I exported was composed by several images that taken at the same place in different time.

I want to obtain the pixel value change of my region of interest.
However, I have problem with exporting every pixel value of those images (take at same place but different time).

Could anyone tell me how to do?
Please help me!!!

***Here's the code with text.***

```js
// Filter an image collection by date and region to make a
// min pixel composite.


// Create a S2 composite for 2015-06-01 to 2017-10-24, and filter by
// the bounds of the FeatureCollection.
var COPERNICUS = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2015-06-01', '2017-10-24')
    .filterBounds(geometry);

// Select the min pixel.
var min = COPERNICUS.min();

// Select the red, green and blue bands.
var result = min.select('B4', 'B3', 'B2');
Map.addLayer(result, {gain: '0.1, 0.1, 0.1',scale:10});
Map.setCenter(135.3735, 34.4794, 5);

var band4 = result.select('B4').rename('b4_min')
.addBands(result.select('B3').rename('b3_min'))
.addBands(result.select('B2').rename('b2_min'));

// Export the image to an Earth Engine asset.
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: result,
  description: 'S2min10m',
  assetId: 'S2min10m',
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
  region: geometry,
});
```

Comment: Hi @BEAR  Thank you for your advice. I edited the question and added the code as text.

Comment: What do you mean by "pixel value change"? The difference between minimum and maximum or some other multi-temporal statistic?

Comment: Hi @Kersten. Thanks for your reply. I mean the "multi-temporal statistic". (pixel values of the same pixel but different time.)

Comment: So you want to export the whole image stack - why? You can calculate these statistics in GEE  just like you used `.min()` for the minimum. You can get pretty much any statistic you want (min, max, stdDev, percentiles, ...) - see the reference: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eereducerpercentile

Comment: @Kersten   Thank you for the information. Because I want to know the pixel number of changes,the time of change and the magnitude of change. In order to analysis land use changes or some other  phenomenon.

Comment: All of this should be achievable within GEE. Exporting a stack of images however is rather hard and would be better achieved by downloading the images directly from their sources and building the image stack locally.

Comment: I think it could be achievable within GEE too. That's true. It will spend a lot of time downloading and building images.  So,my goal is to obtain pixel values of the area and the period of time I've chosen without exporting the whole image stack.  I hope I can make it.

Comment: Hi @dor.F, do you want a set of values (throughout the years) of every pixel in your ROI? just one pixel? an statistic of the ROI throughout the years? It is not clear to me how the expected result would look like..

Comment: Hi @RodrigoE.Principe. Thanks for your reply. I want a set of values (throughout the years) of every pixel in my ROI.  I think it might a table which contains "ID of pixel","bands","pixel values","data" etc.

Comment: Id of every pixel? ok, that is not very common.. neither 'easy' to perform.. will take time and a lot of EE resources.. how big is your roi?

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe , Yes, I hope it will be possible.  about 2,300 square kilometers

Answer (score 1):

I am also a beginner in GEE, but I think that you can achieve your demand through calculating local derivatives (subsequent value minus previous one and dividing by difference of time), and co-erecting them with the timestamps. This may give you something like, peak values and troughs that could be easily retrieved. I also feel that the satellite data could be noisy so some sort of curve smoothing may be necessary.